# Why does the stored procedures not execute the rest of the code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, which was written by another developer whi I have subsequently replaced. At the beginning of their store procedures they delete / drop the table using the following code:

```
EXEC DBA.usp_DeleteTableByName 'Customer_Import'
```

It appears though that the above line of the code is the only one, which gets executed as at the rest of the code within this stored procedure performs a SELECT INTO to recreate and populate the Customer_Import table.

Why would the stored procedure stop executing after the above line of code has been successfully executed?

Comment: Are errors being swallowed by a `try..catch` block that isn't re-raising the error?

Comment: Did they forget to set `xact_abort` on? [Why you should always include `set xact_abort, nocount on;` - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpXACT_ABORT)

Comment: post the other part of procedure

Comment: First question is why would you replace a drop / create statement with another SP?

Comment: It does use a try catch and it is capturing errors successfully but not in relation to the table being dropped after the execution of the above line of code.

Comment: I am of the same opinion as you and I am going to re-write the stored procedure but I am just interested to know why it would not continue executing past the line code I've included in my original question.

Comment: Without seeing the code how could we possibly help? how do you know it doesn't execute anything else?